# Design pattern for Shape Collision C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, inheritance

so i'm currently looking into the best possible designs for a objects (circles, rectangles, etc.) that inherit from Shape. I'm currently using dynamic dispatch, but this requires alot of modification when a new shape is added. Ideally i'd like something along the lines of so that when I add a new shape I don't have to spend an age updating multiple files.

```
public class Shape() {
    public:
    virtual bool detectCollision(Shape *shape);
};
```

Then have other classes be able to derive that in different ways, IE

```
public class Circle : public Shape {
    public:
    bool detectCollision(Square *square);
    bool detectCollision(Circle *circle);
};
```

I'd like to avoid having long `if/else` statements if possible, and don't believe the logic for this should all be done inside of `Shape` using some form of `dynamic_casting`, as ideally `Shape` would not know what was inheriting it.

Is there a solution that fits these needs? I've heard about `Templates` but i'm not sure how I would implement that here, is there an example some one could make, maybe?

Comment: Have you considered Factory design pattern? You can use it with template implementation.

Comment: It seems like you need double dispatch methods here. Chapter 11 of Modern C++ design by Alexadrescu describes exactly the problem you are facing along with a very elegant solution. If I am not mistaken a double-dispatch method is already implemented in Alexandrescu's library "Loki": http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/.

Comment: Hey @linuxfever, that's actually what I'm wanting to avoid. Double dispatch means I would have to ensue that `Shape` new all that classes that have derived it and I would have to update code in multiple places.

Comment: Hey @Nik, I haven't considered a factory design pattern yet. That might be a great solution for my problem

Comment: @Thomas: that is not necessarily true. Alexandrescu's book proposes a solution where you have a dynamic map whose keys are type_identidiers (eg "Circle", "Rectangle" etc) and mapped values which point to the appropriate functions. The best part is that when you add a new class in the hierarchy you do not need to change existing code. If you do a google search you can find that chapter of the book available to download.

Comment: Any information about what "shape" will cover? Only 2D shapes or 3D n-D?
Any information about how collisions will be computed?
2D: You could give each Shape a `getContour()` method which samples the contour of the object in relevant regions and the `detectCollision`method will check whether that contour lies within its own shape.
This will give some new problems, for example in what kind of resolution would you sample a circle? And there are many cases where the collision detection won't be symmetric that way...

Comment: @Micka: well, problem is, "sampling" (i.e. general solution) is much slower than a specialized solution. A Circle-Circle, Square-Square and Square-Circle collisions can be found in just a few mathematical operations, if you know the types. "Generic" solution will just kill performance.

Comment: The shapes are all 2d, on a 2d plane. The issue is keeping performance in a way that we can also extend Shape class to include a new Shape 'Triangle', without having to alter every other class. That is, I don't want "Shape" to deal with the collision between a circle-circle, and square-square. I've had some good suggestions on using a templated collisionhandler for that, and it seems like a good idea. Now I'm able to extend Shape, and just update the CollisionHandler, instead of having to update Square, Circle an Shape, to make them away of triangle collision.

Comment: @DarkWanderer:
All depends on the needs regarding performance and OOP desires (and the number of expected different objects). Encapsulating all collision detection in a collisionhandler might not be nicest OOP, while a generic collision detection might have performance and/or precision drawbacks.

Comment: @Micka: Well, a "beautiful" OOP solution which decreases performance by two orders and more (as the one you're mentioning) is an anti-pattern, IMHO.

Comment: @DarkWanderer: That's why a combination might be the most used collision detection technique in performance critical tasks (arbitrary object shape): Approximate the shape by a bounding box which provides fast/easy collision detection and fall back to concrete (generic) collision detection if bounding boxes collide. If combined with a hierarchy, same sampling issues apply.
But if there are only a few objects present at the same time but hundreds of different object classes exist, you probably can live with a slow (but fast enough) generic pattern instead of writing `n^2` collision functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi Thomas and thanks for your question,

In general using dynamic_cast is worse. Most type specific method calls should be solved during compile time not runtime. In consequence you have to use RTTI, waste performance and your code is not that error prone as checked type safety from the compiler.

```
class Shape
{
public:
  bool colidesWithOtherShape( Shape other ) { return CollisionManager::areShapesCollding( *this, other );  }
}

class CollisionManager
{
public:
  template< typename _T, typename _N >
  static bool areShapesColliding( _T, _N );
};

template <>
bool CollisionManager::areShapesColliding( Circle c, Circle c2 )
{
  return Point::distance( c.getMidPoint(), c.getMidPoint() ) < c.getRadius() + c2.getRadius(); 
}
```

This way your code is type safe and all your collision detection can be implemented in one file or more if you want to but pay attention to your namespaces this can cause some weird behavior from the method look up.

In case of multiple Shapes map all Methods with a specific Shape as second argument to the same Method with the shape as first argument.

```
template< typename _T >
bool CollisionManager::areShapesColliding( _T shape, Circle c )
{
  return CollisionManager::areShapesColliding( c, shape );
}
```

Now just implement all your collision detections from Circle for all other shapes. Ie. for an axis aligned rectangle:

```
template<>
bool CollisionManager::areShapesColliding( Circle circle, Rectangle rectangle )
{
  Point closestPointToCircle = circle.midPoint();

  if( closestPointToCircle.x() > rectangle.right() ) closestPointToCircle.setX( rectangle.right() );
  else if( closestPointToCircle.x() < rectangle.left() ) closestPointToCircle.setX( rectangle.left() );

  if( closestPointToCircle.y() > rectangle.bottom() ) closestPointToCircle.setY( rectangle.bottom() );
  else if( closestPointToCircle.y() < rectangle.top() ) closestPointToCircle.setY( rectangle.top() );

  return point_distance( closestPointToCircle, circle.midPoint() ) <= circle.radiant();
}

template<>
bool CollisionManager::areShapesColliding( Rectangle rect1, Rectangle rect2 )
{
  Point distancePoint = rect1.getMidPoint() - rect2.getMidPoint();
  unsigned long xAxisDistance = abs( distancePoint.x() );
  unsigned long yAxisDistance = abs( distancePoint.y() );

  return xAxisDistance <= ( rect1.width() + rect2.width() ) / 2 &&
         yAxisDistance <= ( rect1.heigth() + rect2.height() ) / 2;
}
```

If you use C++11 (-std=c++11 Linkeflag) you can detect not implemented collision detections at compile time.

```
template< typename _T, typename _N >
bool CollisionManager::areShapesColliding( )
{
  static_assert( false, "your assert" );
}
```

For a runtime solution you need to solve the type at runtime. Because im running out of time here just an example:

```
template<>
bool CollisionManager::areShapesColliding( Shape* shape1, Shape* shape2 )
{
  if( ( Circle* c1 = dynamic_cast<Circle*>( shape1 ) ) != nullptr )
  {
    if( ( Circle* c2 = dynamic_cast<Circle*> ) != nullptr )
    {
      return CollisionManager::areShapesColliding( *c1, *c2 );
    }
    else if( ( Square* s2 = dynamic_cast< Square* >( shape2 ) ) != nullptr )
    {
      return CollisionManager::areShapesColliding( *c1, *s2 );
    }
  }
  //else... if first is square...
  return false; //no matching type found
}
```

Not a nice solution but it capsulate your problem and don't mess your code in your shapes.

I hope I could help you. Have further questions, please let me know.

Michael

Comment: Hey sorry to bother, but could you give just a little bit more help? What exactly am I needing to put in say Circle.cpp and Square.cpp to ensure if a users attempts to circle.collideWith(square), and square.collideWith(circle), they get the same result? this code is excellent, thanks for the support.

Comment: first extend your shape base class with the code given. second create a new class like the collision manager given. Third provide the specializations for your types in this case _T = circle and _N = square

Comment: I think i follow. I've impl collisionhandler in the fashion you've suggested, and also update Shapes.cpp to use it. Now if I create circle.cpp, extend Shapes and just run circle.detectCollision(square), given I have that algorithm in Collisionhandler, it should work? ;D

Comment: Thanks for the update. My only issue is that now I'm receiving `error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000013) "public: static bool __cdecl CollisionManager::detectCollision<class Shape,class Shape>(class Shape,class Shape)" (??$detectCollision@VShape@@V1@@CollisionManager@@$$FSA_NVShape@@0@Z) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall Shape::detectCollision(class Shape)" (?detectCollision@Shape@@$$FQAE_NV1@@Z)`. Is this because I have to impl some other function to ensure we pass the correct types?

Comment: exactly thats one of the main aspects why c++ is so strong and error prone if used correctly :) i've update my answer with an example how to implement a rectangle to the system. you do not have to implement all collision detections in the implementation file of your collision manager and you do not need to wrap it into a class. But it makes life easier and as i said if you split up the specialization into different files you need to know exactly what you are doing. May change the static collisionManager to a prototype if u have different collision system later or implement one in OpenCL...

Comment: Hey! Your advice has been great, I cannot thank you enough. My current issue is that I'm storing `vector<Shape*> shapes` and i'm moving a Shape every so often, and then calling `shape1.detectCollision(shape2)`, inside some nested loops. This is obviously calling the `Shape` to `Shape` collision, even though say Shape1 is actually a rectangle that extends `Shape`. My question is, do I have to do something inside of `Rectangle`, so that it knows to use the right `CollisionHandler` method?

Comment: Try tho think of what the compiler is doing. you call rect.detectCollisiont( circle ) ie. this calls indirect CollisionManager::detectCollison( Rectangle, Circle ). The compiler searches now for this signature and finds the template we made where Circle is the second argument as a best fit. he creates then a method that calls CollsionManager::detectCollision( Circle, Rectangle ) searching for this signature will give the compiler and runtime your implemented collision detection. The method lookup works automatically :) this is what you asked for ;)

Comment: When I implement the method `CollisionHandler::detectCollision( _T shape, someShape c) { return CollisionHandler::detectCollision(c, shape)`, as described above. I receive a `unable to match function definition to an existing declaration` error. Do I need to declare `detectCollision(_T, SomeShape)`, as well as `detectCollision(_T, _N)` ?

Comment: All I know is if I run `Shape* circle = new Circle(5, 5, 5);   Shape* square = new Square(5, 5, 5);  
 cout << circle->detectCollision(*square);`  , it attempts to detect collisions between two `Shape` instead of a `Circle` and `Square`

Comment: might this be the same problem?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch#Double_dispatch_is_more_than_function_overloading

Comment: Hey Micka, that was double dispatch problem I was originally tryingg to resolve. I thought this user had suggested a solution that fixed that, by using the CollisionHandler, however it doesn't seem to function as described.

Comment: sorry for misleading this is a only compile time based solution, making the decision at runtime you have use some virtual overloading normally you would provide some kind of id that identify the type you are dealing with. i will make an example at sunday

Comment: Hey, thanks for preparing an example for Sunday, it'll be interesting to read. Unfortunately that won't help the situation i'm in as the deadline for this is in half an hour! Interestingly, I was wanting to get a more "sleak" solution to the problem, I guess I will just go with my initial double dispatch solution.

Comment: anyway making your types pointer and implement one specialization for Shape* Shape* and dynamic cast them to type that can be resolved at compile time would be a quick workaround

Comment: Oh? How would I do that?

Comment: Yeah, I came up with something similar. Thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to decide first whether you need to know the type of your object at compile time or not. I.e., such approach:

```
public class Shape{
    public:
    virtual bool detectCollision(Square *square);
    virtual bool detectCollision(Circle *circle);
};

Shape* shape1,shape2;
shape1 = GetNewCircleOrSquareByRandom();
shape2 = GetNewCircleOrSquareByRandom();
shape1->detectCollision(shape2);
```

will not work, because compiler does not (and can not) know which object is actually there.

As pointed by @linuxfever, it's a known problem of [double dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch). One solution is provided in the Wikipedia article by the link (pretty similar to yours).

If you know what collides with what at compile time, however, you can use templates, as you have correctly guessed:

```
// In header
template<class _T1, class _T2> bool detectCollision(_T1* object1, _T2* object2) {
    // Generic implementation
    // Or just an #error "Sorry! Don't know how to collide those two objects"
}

template<> bool detectCollision(Square* object1, Circle* object2) {
    // Specific implementaiton of Square vs. Circle
}

template<> bool detectCollision(Circle* object1, Square* object2) {
    return detectCollision(object2,object1);
}
// etc
```

Answer (score 3):

I do not think you can get around of specialized algorithms to detect/improve collision detection. Having some shapes A and B you need a function knowing both types to apply the proper algorithm. This leads to:

```
class Shape() {
    public:
    // Not virtual!
    // Avoiding pointers.
    bool detectCollision(const Shape&) const;
};

bool Shape::detectCollision(const Shape& other)  const {
   if(is_rectangle(*this) && is_rectangle(other)) 
       return rectangle_rectangle_collision(*this, other); 
       // Where rectangle_rectangle_collision is a local function
       // in a source file 

       // and so on ...
}
```

Generalizing it, you could have a map of collision functions, register new algorithms in Shape and select a specialized or generic one (based on polygons) in detectCollision.

You might be tempted to use templates for collision detection, but thy are useless (unless you dispatch) in dynamic polymorphism.

Comment: Getting around the algorithm wasn't the goal. In my head I'm thinking "if I was to pick this up as a library, and wanted to add my own Shape Triangle, only being able to inherit the existing Shape object, how would i do that?". The logic for the algorithms atm is defined within each respective class (circle, square, etc).

Comment: @ThomasAnderson Why should a circle know a rectangle (are you duplicating algorithms in circle and rectangle)?